# Reload ASP.Net page with data from static method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a static method on my ASP.Net page, and at the end of the method I want to cause my page to reload. My problem is that this is a search page, and my static method is deleting an item from the search results on the page from the database. So, that item should disappear from the GridView on the page after the refresh.

Why is this a static method? Because it's a WebMethod that's being called from javascript on the page.

Below is my code. First the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delItem(assetID) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?'))
            PageMethods.DelItem(assetID);
    }
</script>
```

The markup for the GridView:

```
<table><tr><td><asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gvResults" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="true" 
                 AllowPaging="true" OnSorting="gvResults_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvResults_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvResults_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="AssetID" 
                EmptyDataText="No Results!" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Bold="true" EmptyDataRowStyle-BackColor="AliceBlue" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Size="XX-Large" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Large" />
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Size="Medium" CssClass="pagination-ys"  />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetName" SortExpression="AssetName" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetType" SortExpression="AssetType" HeaderText="Asset Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ManName" SortExpression="ManName" HeaderText="Manufacturer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ResponsiblePerson" SortExpression="ResponsiblePerson" HeaderText="Primary Support" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" SortExpression="IPAddress" HeaderText="IP Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OSName" SortExpression="OSName" HeaderText="OS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Office" SortExpression="Office" HeaderText="Location" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/pencil-img.png" Target="_parent" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/trash-img.png" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("AssetID", "javascript:delItem({0});") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView></td></tr></table>
```

Note that the last HyperLink calls the javascript method delItem.

Finally, the code-behind:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static void DelItem(int assetID)
    {
        ServerContext context = new ServerContext();
        string paramNames = @"@AssetID ";
        string storedProc = "EXEC delAsset " + paramNames;
        object[] sqlParam = new object[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@AssetID", assetID)
        };

        try
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(storedProc, sqlParam);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            string err;
            if (sqlex.InnerException != null)
                err = sqlex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                err = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
```

After the try block I have tried calling javascript to reload the page:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler), typeof(Page), "", "document.location.reload(true);", true);
```

I've also tried `window.location.reload`. Nothing happens with either one, despite numerous links claiming this was the way to go.

I've also tried the following instead of the javascript:

```
DisplayApplicationSummary das = new DisplayApplicationSummary();
das.Search_Click();
```

where DisplayApplicationSummary is the class on the page, but because it's being called within a static method, when das.Search_Click() gets called, it doesn't see any of the search parameters that have been entered on the page.

And here's an abbreviated version of what happens when the Search button is clicked:

```
public Hashtable SearchParams { get; set; }

protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name_search = tbName.Text;
        int type_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
        int office_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOffice.SelectedValue);
        string respperson_search = ddlRespPerson.SelectedValue;
        int manufacturer_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlManufacturer.SelectedValue);
        int OS_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOS.SelectedValue);
        int usergroup_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUserGroup.SelectedValue);
        string ipaddress_search = BasicSwitchIpAddress.Value;
        bool search_deleted = cbDeleted.Checked;

        Hashtable searchparams = new Hashtable();
        searchparams.Add("name", name_search);
        searchparams.Add("type", type_search);
        searchparams.Add("office", office_search);
        searchparams.Add("respperson", respperson_search);
        searchparams.Add("manufacturer", manufacturer_search);
        searchparams.Add("os", OS_search);
        searchparams.Add("usergroup", usergroup_search);
        searchparams.Add("ipaddress", ipaddress_search);
        searchparams.Add("searchdeleted", search_deleted);

        SearchParams = searchparams;

        Search_Click();
    }

public void Search_Click()
    {
        string name_search;
        int type_search;
        int office_search;
        string respperson_search;
        int manufacturer_search;
        int OS_search;
        int usergroup_search;
        string ipaddress_search;
        bool search_deleted;

        if (SearchParams == null)
        {
            name_search = tbName.Text;
            type_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
            office_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOffice.SelectedValue);
            respperson_search = ddlRespPerson.SelectedValue;
            manufacturer_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlManufacturer.SelectedValue);
            OS_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOS.SelectedValue);
            usergroup_search = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUserGroup.SelectedValue);
            ipaddress_search = BasicSwitchIpAddress.Value;
            search_deleted = cbDeleted.Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            name_search = SearchParams["name"].ToString();
            type_search = Convert.ToInt32(SearchParams["type"]);
            office_search = Convert.ToInt32(SearchParams["office"]);
            respperson_search = SearchParams["respperson"].ToString();
            manufacturer_search = Convert.ToInt32(SearchParams["manufacturer"]);
            OS_search = Convert.ToInt32(SearchParams["os"]);
            usergroup_search = Convert.ToInt32(SearchParams["usergroup"]);
            ipaddress_search = SearchParams["ipaddress"].ToString();
            search_deleted = Convert.ToBoolean(SearchParams["searchdeleted"]);
        }
...
}
```

As you can see above, I tried creating a public Hashtable variable called SearchParams and populating it with the search parameters when the search button is first clicked, but the static method of course doesn't see the Hashtable when Search_Click() is called again.

So I'm stumped. To sum up, I want to refresh my page of search results to reflect the fact that one item has been removed. How can I do this?

Comment: Any chance you can add an update panel and just use that? (with a postback button.) It will only update whatever is inside of it and leave the rest of the page alone.

Comment: Just want to be sure I understand - so the HyperLink would just mark the row for deletion and then the update button would perform the actual deletion? Is that what you're thinking? Do update panels allow you to ask the user for confirmation prior to performing whatever operation is being called? I've never used one before, so am unsure. Thanks!

Comment: I've found a way to deal with this, but I don't understand why it works. After the call to PageMethods.DelItem in the javascript, I've added 2 lines. One is an alert, and the second is event.preventDefault(). The I do a location.reload(2). Both the alert and the event.preventDefault must be there, but if they are the location.reload works. Does anyone know why?